# See list of past wifi server connections in Mac

Tags: network, macos

Is there a way on Mac to see the full list of past wifi server connections, along with the certs the servers used to identify themselves?

Where is this info stored in Mac?

Comment: Have you looked in the keychain?

Comment: @Allan, Keychain has logs? It seems to only show the current cert cache.

Comment: No, the Keychain itself.  I just checked mine and it shows expired certs for different things  (though I have none for WiFi as I don't use cert based authentication)

Comment: @Allan, Yea most of that cache itself has been deleted on this box, so I'm hoping there's a log like eventvwr or syslog that holds a record. ¶ Btw for the existing cache, is the date modified of rows also the same as the date created?